# Make a tablet with a HP 15-p158sa touch display

Tags: display, touchscreen, laptop

So, a mate of mine managed to short his laptop somehow. Around the charging port the plastic melted, I’ve disassembled the laptop and it looks fried. 
I took out an 1500GB hard drive and a 8GB RAM card and most importantly a touch screen display.
The laptop is a HP 15-p158sa. Here’s a picture of the actual display.
https://ibb.co/j1vBNF

Now this is where I need some help.
How can I hook it up to a raspberry pi in order to make this a big, cool tablet?

Is there any way to use the HDD and maybe run Windows 7/8/10 on it?

Comment: It looks like the picture only show the touch screen not the display.

Answer (score 2):

This question comes up regularly.

The answer is no.

You can't use the screen and Windows 7/8/10 will not run on the Pi.

There is something called Windows IoT which will run on the Pi3 (and possibly on the Pi2, I don't remember), but that is not Windows as you mean.

Comment: Alright, scratch the Windows part. So I can’t use the monitor as a touchscreen one with the raspberry pi? I know you can use almost any old one as a display but I was hoping I can keep the “touchscreen” part.

Comment: @Chris If you can use the laptop screen as a display you will make a fortune - just tell other people how to do so.  Once the laptop screen has been separated from the laptop it becomes a useless piece of junk.

Comment: I have down voted this, because you can use the display with a HDMI to LVDS interface kit. The answer about Windows is partly correct. It is therotically possible to run a Windows on a Raspberry Pi in a virtuall environment (virtualbox).

Answer (score 1):

There are HDMI to LVDS kits sold on the Internet, which may get your screen working with the RPi ([example](http://www.ebay.fr/itm/HDMI-DVI-VGA-Driver-LVDS-Inverter-Kit-Convert-a-Bare-Laptop-LCD-into-Monitor-/111115624120)). You'll need to find out your LCD part number (should be written on the LCD somewhere, or can be found in the repair manual), and the seller will tell you if they can find a suitable adapter for it or not.

Regarding the touchscreen part, it's a bit harder to figure out but may be possible if you have the skills. Take a look at [touchscreens](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/tree/master/drivers/input/touchscreen) supported by Linux and check if your laptop screen is supported. Then find out what the interface is (often i2c) and where its electrical connections are located. Then see if you can hook it up to the RPi and try loading the driver.

Mind you, your "tablet" won't be as cool as you imagine, as it will be permanently hooked to a wall-wart adapter to power both the screen and the RPi.

Of course, there's no way to run regular Windows on the RPi.

Comment: I’ve looked into it and I’m happy so far. My only concern is that I can’t use the display as a touchscreen one... Any ideas?

Comment: @Chris that depends on the touchscreen interface. I have an HP laptop with a touchscreen (11k108-nf), and I can see my touchscreen is an i2c device, meaning it's theoretically possible to make it work with an RPi.

Comment: Do I need a module or something? As you can see there are two wires sticking out of the screen... Once I hook up the controller to the screen what do I do with them?

Comment: I’m looking to save myself £50 as that’s how much an Air bar costs lol

Comment: Nah scratch thay, nevermind lol. Thing is I love electronics but I still have  A LOT to learn, and I’m excited to learn new stuff, so every now and again I like to challenge myself and come up with a new useless but flashy gadget haha. This is why I keep bothering you guys haha. I’ll make an arcade cabinet with retro pi or something like that. I’ll post pictures when it’s done :)